# Vim - inconsistency between :tabnext N and :tabprev N

Tags: vim

From Vim's `:help tabs`:

```
:tabp[revious] {count}
:tabN[ext] {count}
{count}<C-PageUp>
{count}gT   Go {count} tab pages back.  Wraps around from the first one
            to the last one.
```

While

```
:tabn[ext] {count}
{count}<C-PageDown>
{count}gt   Go to tab page {count}.  The first tab page has number one.
```

Finally, parameterless `:tabn` behaves consistent with `:tabp` and `:tabp 1`.

**Why is that**? Is it only to make `3gt` jump to tab 3 instead of 3 tabs ahead? Nothing prevents vim from having `:tabn 3` and `:tabjump 3`, and bind `Ngt` to use `:tabjump` rather than `:tabn`. Frankly, to me this looks like a design error.

**Can we have** `:tabp N` forward equivalent using only built-in commands? I noticed one can't use `:tabprev -2`, for example. If there is no built-in counterpart to `:tabp N`, then why have `:tabp N` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is inconsistent, but I also find the available choices convenient. It allows both for iterating back / forward one by one, as well as absolute addressing.

Why is it that way? You could search through the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) archives for messages when this feature had been proposed / a patch submitted, or ask there if anyone remembers the background. (Note that there are many other features with less-than-optimal interfaces; it's a volunteer project with a single bottleneck BDFL at the top, and the [worse is better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better) mentality certainly applies here.)

To perform relative tab navigation in forward direction, you can use:

```
:execute 'tabnext' tabpagenr() + N
```

You can easily define a custom command or mapping if you find this useful.